# Administrator being able to delete any user from the database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a simple small application which involves an admin having the ability to update and delete information or individual user's from a database. Basically, so far the administrator can view all the current registered user's in a table format on a page. I need to know how I can delete or update the user information based on the user in each row, so assuming based on their actual userID. So far I have been able to extract all the user's from the database and put them into a table, and using JSTL fill in the necessary table values(username, email, etc..).
I do not know, the proper process for doing this, and do not know how to code up the controller to handle this specific task. So far my controller is like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/deleteUser")
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", required= false) Integer id) {

    usersService.delete(id);
    return "users";

}
```

where the request mapping comes from a button in the table, and "return users;" just returns back to the same jsp page which displays all the users. This is a little buggy, and I would like to know what would be the proper and best way to implementing this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Check the users Authority with the Principal.

```
   @RequestMapping("/deleteUser")
    public String deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", required= false, Principal princiapl) Integer id) {
    // Check if user has admin authority using principal.getAuthorities();
    }
```

You could also use the @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") annotation and lock down the method to the admin role.